# Does having different model of gun affect multiplayer games?

Tags: counter-strike, counter-strike-condition-zero

I was playing counterstrike today and in our server our admin said that a guy had a different AWP model and animation. He was just fragging everyone.

Does it affect the game or was he just good?

Comment: Skins, gun designs etc don't affect gameplay as they are just cosmetics. They guy was probably just better than the other players in that game, unless you can prove he was cheating.

Comment: @n_palum 1 week ago he was noobest one

Comment: Possibility that he played a lot since then and got better? It's not that hard of a game to practice and become better at - especially if you are playing vs people that aren't that good and haven't been practicing either.

Comment: @n_palum Well I played with him last 15 min he wall banged some guys and admin banned him. I guess He must be using WH.

Comment: Well there ya go - if admin proved or suspected he cheated there's your answer.

Comment: A model can give you an advantage, but you can't be that godlike with just a new model. That guy probably had something else running and only used the model as excuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about Counter-Strike: Global Offensive, it's just a joke. The skins in CS:GO have **NO** influence on any stats of the weapon.

But if he is using custom skins in e.g. Counter-Strike: Source it is possible to get an advantage. For example you could have a scout skin with a laser pointer, marking the middle of your screen, which helps to be accurate when "no-scoping". Seen that kind of skins in the past.

Comment: Yep I am not talking about CSGO as I know about it , I am talking about 1.6

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of debate on this. Some say that they do but it is invisible in the stats listing whereas others say that it is purely cosmetic ( and a waste of money). As of now valve have yet to put this matter to rest so I would say that it is probably the fact that he has a certain skin makes him play better as it has a physiological effect but no-one can be sure. Even I am not.